# in rails I'm sending a var to view and but in js file is nil

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, erb

I'm sending a var in rails to use it in the view, I have a js file name charts.js.erb that is called and I need to use the var in that js file but is nil

in my controller a have the method

```
  def index
    @asd = 'hellow'
  end
```

in my view i can do

```
.div= @asd
```

but in my javascript file

```
alert('<%= @asd %>');
```

@asd var is nil, i've tested using other ruby code an works, but the vars doesn't work

Comment: Is that alert in the same view as your div? If yes, it should work. If it's somewhere in assets/javascripts, then no, it shouldn't work.

Comment: Try using respond_to block.

Comment: NO @SergioTulentsev, I have the file charts.js attached with that js, and that alert does not show anithing. i test the ads var and is nil

Comment: @jacr1102: well yes, that's to be expected. assets are rendered way before your controller has the chance to set the var.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev there is no way to use it ?, I need to assign it to javascript vars in my view to use it in jv file later ?

Comment: @jacr1102: the easiest workaround - put the javascript directly into the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how ERB works with JavaScript. The JS files are generated before runtime, so they do not have access to dynamic server values like that.

The pattern that I usually follow is to place the server-generated value somewhere in the DOM for the JS to pick up.

```
<div id="asd" data-asd="<%= @asd %>">
```

Then if you're using jQuery, for example:

```
var asd = $('#asd').data('asd');
```